# How to pass arguments in Azure Pipeline to a powershell script

Tags: xml, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm working with Azure Pipeline (Creating a Build/Release Pipeline) to deploy to service fabric. I have a task that uploads the *sfpkg file to a storage account. After the file is uploaded, I get the SASToken and i want to pass that SAS token to the next task. The next task is taking the SASToken and storing it in the XML file. The problem is that the SASToken has "&"s as part of the entire token and XML doesn't respond well to &s. There is no way I can manipulate the SASToken.

I get the following error "The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string"

How can I edit the SASToken once i've gotten it? This is all being done via the Azure Pipeline. I even tried putting a PS script to just write out the token to see what I am getting and even the powershell script gave me the same error.

Comment: Eventually I need to take that XML file and convert it to JSON and have all this information in there as well.

Comment: Are you sure PS is throwing the same error? I can't see why echoing a string with '&' would throw an error.

Comment: Yes, when i do a simple write to the xml file using PS i get the same error because it doens't like the & in the XML file.

Comment: Oh I was assuming your PS script was printing to the console. Couldn't you just replace all instances of `&` with `"&"`? I'm not familiar with azure, but I know it's not hard to do in PS